# Is it recommended or possible to run RGZPFM on two different physical files at the same time?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Good day, With our current world epidemic we have a one to two day period where our IBM server wont be used, we have identified a few tables that we need to reorganize to improve available space.

I am a developer not an IBM expert.

What I would like to know is , Is it recommended to run  `RGZPFM` on more than one file at a time for example having more than one green screen session open and in each one run the command on different tables?

Or is it better to do one at a time?

I have one day to do a few tables and thought that if I am able to run it for multiple tables at once it would somehow be faster to complete?

Here is a list of tables(without table names) that I plan to `RGZPFM` so that you can get an idea of the processing or rows involved.

[image]

Comment: this is not a programming question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, it depends. If the machine in question has many disks and more than one CPU, parallelising rgzpfm will show an overall speed improvement.

I recommend against using parallel green screen sessions, because depending on licensing, green screen sessions can be performance crippled.

I'd suggest to SBMJOB CMD(RGZPFM …) for each table. Batch jobs normally run more effectively than in Green Screen, because of different scheduling options.

Since your tables aren't so big, I'd suggest to run batch jobs when there's not too much activity on the system, because tables will be locked while they are reorganised.

Also, timed jobs (wrkjobscde, backups) and external accesses (ODBC) will be affected if locked tables should be accessed. Keep this in mind.

Comment: RGZPFM now has options that allow it to run without locking the tables so other jobs can still use the table.  I use these options RBDACCPTH(*NO) ALWCANCEL(*YES) LOCK(*SHRUPD).  The command may run longer if the tables are being updated and could affect performance of other jobs using the table but will all run without errors.

Comment: "depending on licensing, green screen sessions can be performance crippled." Are you sure that this is still the case. It was the case for Power 5 Standard Edition systems, but Power 6 removed that. So unless you are on a box that has been unsupported for many years, there is no interactive tax.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: The OP did not state which machine or OS release he's using, so it might be the case for him.